Subscription offer, Access to Azure Active Directory, is being deprecated
I've got an email from Microsoft:
Your subscription offer, Access to Azure Active Directory, will be disabled on May 16, 2024
You’re receiving this email because you’re an account administrator of the subscription of offer type, Access to Azure Active Directory.
Access to Azure Active Directory subscriptions were subscriptions that were used to connect to the Azure portal. These subscriptions aren’t required anymore because the new Azure Portal uses your Azure Active Directory access (also known as Microsoft Entra ID), so we’re deprecating these subscriptions. As a part of this deprecation, you can either cancel your subscription now or it will be disabled on May 16, 2024 and will be deleted on July 15, 2024.If you currently have active resources in your Access to Azure Active Directory subscription, please upgrade to a new pay-as-you-go subscription by submitting a support ticket below.
Will this affect me and my tenant? I mean if this subscription cancels, this won't delete my users and their mailboxes? Still confused with this...

I would open a support ticket. Only you and Microsoft will know if anything will be affected.

@ArchitectJamie already did, but I don't have that much kind of support, they said I've gotta reach Azure support, but unfrotunately for some reason the sumbit form can not be send... Have you had some experience like this, or know someone who had? I mean from this email they are just retiring some old kind of subscriptions, hopefully it won't affect the workflow of everything else...

I would log in and look at the subscription, see if there are any resources in there. If there are not, you are probably fine. I have one of these subscriptions too, have been an Azure AD/Entra ID customer since 2015 or so, so this being a legacy thing checks out for me. Thank you for sharing this, I have spent the years wondering what that subscription might be, without doing anything about it.

I just looked at the same subscription in my Azure portal, it does not look like it could have resources in there even if I wanted them, the menu items for resources and resource groups are just missing. But you should check your end.

@KonTheCat Thank you for answer, I will try to check, because I am kinda new on it, just started my administration job, and I get this... I've found this too:
Classic administrators will be deprecated on August 31, 2024. After August 31, 2024, all classic administrators risk losing access to the subscription. Delete Classic Admins who no longer need access or assign an Azure RBAC role for fine-grained access control. On what does this refer to? I mean the name "Access to Azure Active Directory" looks pretty important, but I guess they can't just turn it off like that

@KonTheCat Do you have any kind of guide or tutorial how to take a look at the subscription and check for it?

@Milance so if I understand your situation correctly, you are new to Azure administration, and to this organization, which has some Azure, but not other people that understand Azure well? Not judging or anything, just need to understand the level at which I should do the answer.

@KonTheCat yup exactly kinda new in Azure administration, so I am worried a bit what will happen if this subscription cancels and then deletes at July 15 2024. Will I lose access to my admin panel then? Thank you!

Long story short, it does not look like you will lose anything. Certainly, you won't lose users in Azure AD/Entra ID or mailboxes or anything like that. More details will follow in an answer. For your other question, here are some details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-classic-administrator-roles-are-retiring-on-31-august-2024/#:~:text=On%2031%20August%202024%2C%20Azure,be%20retired%20on%20that%20date.
As a new person administering Azure I think its a good idea for you to at least try to figure that out on your own, RBAC is kind of critical.

@KonTheCat alright, will try to figure out about the RBAC. Thank you so much for effort and answers!

This answer is based substantially on the discussion in the comments under the question. The goal is to get access to all the Azure subscriptions that could exist and then check to see if any resources are deployed in the "Access to Azure Active Directory" subscription.
Some fundamentals: an Azure subscription is a management and billing container for Azure resources. An Azure subscription trusts an Azure AD/Entra ID tenant, you could describe it as joined to such a tenant in the same way that a computer is joined to a directory, more or less. Further, it must be joined to such a tenant, and can only be joined to one such tenant. A tenant, however, can have many different subscriptions.
This next step assumes that you are a Global Administrator in Entra ID/Microsoft 365. If you are not, you need someone who is to do these steps.

Review this article closely and do the steps outlined there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin?tabs=azure-portal
Make sure that you assign yourself the kind of access that you need, to the relevant subscription. Just how much access you need depends on your organization and how you plan to manage Azure. For the purposes of this, Reader access should be enough.
In the Azure portal, find Subscriptions. Then review the "Access to Azure Active Directory" - if it looks like the picture below, you are probably fine. If you have "Resources" or "Resource Groups" in the area circled in red, review what you have there and determine if you need it. If you do need it you probably need to migrate it to a different subscription, I would recommend raising additional questions if you need help with that.



this is such a great explanation! I've done all steps above, and my screen look same as yours, I don't have any resources  and resource groups in the area circled in red like in your picture. Thank you once more, hopefully this will help some other too, because I've seen also others have confusion with this.

I am very happy to have been able to help! Welcome to Azure! If you are going to have a highly privileged account please ensure that you have MFA on it, that is an absolute minimum, deploying Conditional Access is strongly recommended/basically foundational in my experience, but please do that carefully, its easy to lock yourself out especially if you are solo.

thank you! Already setup MFA for my account, but soon I will also try to migrate MFA, probably I will post it here again for help :) ...
This is the link that I've got: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/how-to-authentication-methods-manage?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_IAM

Yep, that looks like the right thing!
